# Scrapely can't train on tags with desired text and an inner tag also with desired text

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, scrapely

I'm trying to use *scrapely* to extract some data from html page.

The html page that I'm trying to scrape contains some html tags that contain both some text to be scraped and an inner tag whose content also needs to be scraped. As a consequence, when I try to train the scraper, I get a `FragmentAlreadyAnnotated` exception because the classifier ends up annotating the outer html tag for both the strings.

Does anyone knows how to circumvent this situation?

I created a minimal working example for you to experiment:

```
import json

from scrapely import HtmlPage, Scraper

train_html = """<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p><span>Example 1</span> * 2018</p>
    <p><span>Example 2</span> * 2017</p>
    <p><span>Example 3</span> * 2016</p>
</body>
</html>"""

test_html = """<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p><span>Example A</span> * 2015</p>
    <p><span>Example B</span> * 2014</p>
    <p><span>Example C</span> * 2013</p>
</body>
</html>"""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    train_page = HtmlPage(url='http://example.com/', page_id=1, body=train_html)
    train_data = {
        'special': ['Example 1', 'Example 2', 'Example 3'],
        'year': ['2018', '2017', '2016']
    }
    test_page = HtmlPage(url='http://example.com/', page_id=2, body=test_html)

    s = Scraper()
    s.train_from_htmlpage(train_page, train_data)

    matches = s.scrape_page(test_page)
    print(json.dumps(matches, indent=4))

    print('Done.')
```

When I try to execute this script, I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/stefano/Workspace/2018/re-searcher/src/main/python/researcher/mwe.py", line 40, in <module>
    s.train_from_htmlpage(train_page, train_data)
  File "/Users/stefano/Workspace/2018/re-searcher/.env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapely/__init__.py", line 44, in train_from_htmlpage
    tm.annotate(field, best_match(value))
  File "/Users/stefano/Workspace/2018/re-searcher/.env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapely/template.py", line 44, in annotate
    self.annotate_fragment(i, field)
  File "/Users/stefano/Workspace/2018/re-searcher/.env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapely/template.py", line 83, in annotate_fragment
    raise FragmentAlreadyAnnotated("Fragment already annotated: %s" % fstr)
scrapely.template.FragmentAlreadyAnnotated: Fragment already annotated: <span data-scrapy-annotate="{&quot;annotations&quot;: {&quot;content&quot;: &quot;year&quot;}}">
```

While I would expect something like:

```
[
    {
        "year": [
            "2015",
            "2014",
            "2013"
        ],
        "special": [
            "Example A",
            "Example B",
            "Example C"
        ]
    }
]
Done.
```

Many thanks in advance!

*Bonus question:* do you know if there is a way to keep each `special` to be associated with the closest `year`? Notice that in some case the year might be missing:

```
<body>
    <p><span>Example D</span> * 2012</p>
    <p><span>Example E</span></p>
    <p><span>Example F</span> * 2011</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but rather an hack.

I created a function that uses RegEx to removes unnecessary spaces and new lines and then looks for patterns like `<X><Y>some text</Y>more text</X>` to replaces them with `<X><Y>some text</Y><span>mote text</span></Y>` (the RegEx might not work with some edge cases, if you spot them please suggest below how to fix it).

By preprocessing any HTML with such function, the aforementioned error never occurs and (almost -- notice the asterisks) produces the expected result, which is:

```
[
    {
        "year": [
           "* 2015",
           "* 2014",
           "* 2013"
        ], 
        "special": [
            "Example A",
            "Example B",
            "Example C"
        ]
    }
]
```

Please find below the revised code:

```
def fix(html: str) -> str:
    html = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', html)
    html = re.sub(r'> <', '><', html)
    html = re.sub(
        r'<([^>]+)>([^<]*)<([^>]+)>([^<]+)</([^>]+)>([^<]+)</([^>]+)>',
        r'<\1>\2<\3>\4</\5><span>\6</span></\7>',
        html
    )
    return html


def clean(text: str) -> str:
    return re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', re.sub(r'<.*>', ' ', text)).strip()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    train_page = HtmlPage(url='http://example.com/', page_id=1, body=fix(train_html))
    train_data = {
        'special': ['Example 1', 'Example 2', 'Example 3'],
        'year': ['2018', '2017', '2016']
    }
    test_page = HtmlPage(url='http://example.com/', page_id=2, body=fix(test_html))

    s = Scraper()
    s.train_from_htmlpage(train_page, train_data)

    matches = s.scrape_page(test_page)
    for match in matches:
        for key in match:
            match[key] = [clean(value) for value in match[key]]
    print(json.dumps(matches, indent=4))

    print('Done.')
```